# How can I center an Oracle Apex command button?

Tags: oracle-apex

Apex only give me two options, left og right align. Is there a way to center a button?

[image]

I want to center the "LÆS MERE" button.

This is how it looks in the Apex designer:
[image] 
Properties for the button:
[image]

Generated html. If I only could replace td align="right" with align="center".

[image]

Comment: Not easily - you'd need to experiment with CSS to move it around.

Comment: How about this CSS: `td[align="right"] {text-align: center}`.  Possibly with some additional selector to confine this to the region in question.

Comment: While there is no "center" in APEX, there is a grid of 12 columns. You can indicate in APEX what column of the grid you want the item to start in.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way, I created a new section with the button and I set it to start in column 6 (middle) and I set the appearence model  to "Interactive Report", this model does not shows header title and it has no border. Here is the result:

[image]